# Schema initiation in Binami postgresql image for kubernetes cluster

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, devops, bitnami, kubernetes-statefulset

I am using bitnami PostgreSQL image to deploy StatfulSet inside my cluster node. I am not sure how to initiate schema for the PostgreSQL pod without building on top of bitnami image. I have looked around on the internet and someone said to use init containers but I am also not sure how exactly I would do that.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Github Readme](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-postgresql) of the Bitnami Docker image:

> When the container is executed for the first time, it will execute the
> files with extensions `.sh`, `.sql` and `.sql.gz` located at
> `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`.
>
> In order to have your custom files inside the docker image you can
> mount them as a volume.

You can just mount such scripts under that directory using a ConfigMap volume. An example could be the following:

First, create the ConfigMap with the scripts, for example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: p-init-sql
  labels:
    app: the-app-name
data:
  01_init_db.sql: |-
    # content of the script goes here
  02_second_init_db.sql: |-
    # more content for another script goes here
```

Second, under `spec.template.spec.volumes`, you can add:

```
volumes:
  - configMap:
      name: p-init-sql
```

Then, under `spec.template.spec.containers[0].volumeMounts`, you can mount this volume with:

```
volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    name: p-init-sql
```

---

With this said, you may find out that it is more easy to use [HELM](https://helm.sh/) Charts.

Bitnami provides HELM Charts for all its images which simplify the usage of such images by a lot (as everything is ready to be installed and configured from a simple `values.yaml` file)

For example, there is such a chart for postgresql which you can find [here](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/postgresql/) and that can be of inspiration in how to configure the docker image even if you decide to write your own Kubernetes resources around that image.

Comment: Thanks!! It was very helpful.